# GameServer World Management

Tags: java, multithreading, server

I'm creating a 2D Game in Java. The world is tile based with a multidimensional Array and I have the architecture for the Server-Client system.
The Users/Connections to the Clients are multithreaded.

Now my question is:
Should my Client send a request to the server to ask for the current world state (with entities etc...) in his view range or should I create another thread in my connection/user class just for sending the world data every servertick?
Or is there even a better solution for sending/requesting the world with his entities?

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: I would believe that any decisions that you make depend on factors that you haven't shared with us, such as number of players, latency requirements, type of game, and so on. However, a common approach would be for the client to request map info around itself, with the server pushing changes and important data to the client whenever such information arises.

Comment: How real time is the game?  If it's a board game it may make sense for the server to send data once somebody moves.  If it's a real time strategy with simultaneous actions, it may work better with the server sending data every tick

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "I have also created the packages"?  Do you mean network packets?

Comment: Yeah i mean the server packages. And i wanted a kind of mmorpg, which requires real time & less latency

Comment: Define "mmorpg", if it's something like RotMG, a mmorpg bullet hell, you need it to be a lot more responsive than something like WoW/RuneScape _(better example: Travian)_.  If you are more descriptive about what you're trying to do and type of game, then we can be more descriptive and helpful

Comment: If it's a 2D game it's more or less like rotmg, but with open world & no hardcore. But with better graphics and not that fast movement. The rendered screen has about 30x30 tiles and the client runs at 60 ticks per second.

Comment: In that case, with bullets flying, enemies roaming, and the player constantly moving and dodging, you're going to be updating each player quite frequently (probably every few server ticks)

Answer (score 0):

In games, very often you never want to trust the client.  The servers word is law and the client should have very little depending on them.

> Should my client send a request to the server to ask for the current world state

Probably not, since the client doesn't know when there is updated information

The server knows when things update and what information to give, it would make more sense for the server to send data to the client when it's needed

---

As to how often to send data, send data whenever something in the clients view changes (either from client actions or just things moving)

This may be often in a fast paced game (ie bullet hell), or less so in a slow game (ie board games)

Comment: So i have to check every tick if something in the players viewport has changed and send if needed the new state of the world in his viewport? Or should i just send the update (ex player 123 moved to 2123|312) ?That would cause that if many players move or attack it has to send a lot of packets...

Comment: In this case it may be better to have updates on a schedule, so if there's a delay the client can detect it.  In a game like this it's going to be rare that nothing changes in the client's view (including health regen, effect timers... they should be simulated on the client, but synced with the server)